# AES encryption with jquery

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt AES locally using the [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#AES) library.
I have the code from the [example](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#AES):

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(mess, pass);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, pass);
```

but the `decrypted` variable is not returing the `mess` variable? Why is that?

Please see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9jrt2ez/)?

Comment: Scroll down and read "The Cipher Output"

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery. Please don't confuse jQuery with plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#The_Hasher_Output):

> The hash you get back isn't a string yet. It's a WordArray object. When you use a WordArray object in a string context, it's automatically converted to a hex string.
>
> [...]
>
> You can convert a WordArray object to other formats by explicitly calling the toString method and passing an encoder.

Replace `decrypted` with `decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8))`, see the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9jrt2ez/1/).